# Java Generics limitations or wrong usage?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class representing a pair of two values of the same type (type which can be any of  a specific set of types ):

```
  public class Pair<E extends AClass>{
      private E var1;
      private E var2; 
  }
```

This class is used by a framework, so it needs a no-argument constructor in which I have to instantiate the 2 variables (var1, var2):

```
  public class Pair<E extends AClass>{
      private E var1;
      private E var2; 

      public Pair(){
           var1 = invoke constructor of type E; 
           var2 = invoke constructor of type E 
      }
  }
```

There are obviously a number of problems here:

1. In order to instantiate the variables I should somehow know its exact type and invoke that specific type's constructor; in the best case this means to have a pretty large if else  statement in the constructor, something like:

   ```
    public Pair(){
          if(var1 instanceof SpecificType1){
             var1 = new SpecificType1(); 
             var2 = new SpecificType2();
          }
     }
   ```
2. Even if I do as above, I will have some problems because var1 is declared of type E and I will get a type mismatch error when trying to instantiate SpecficType1 and to assign the resulted object to var1/var2. In order to make it work, I have to cast to E :

   ```
      var1 = (E)new SpecificType1();
   ```

But this destroys the compile time type checking as I'm trying to cast a specific type to a generic type.

Is this a limitation of the Generics in java or is this scenario a bad one for using Generics ?

Comment: If you have to use `instanceOf` inside a generic container, then you have a design problem.

Comment: You can try [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Notification to the asker (since edits do not notify the asker): I added a simple code sample how to use the factory design pattern in your case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In order to instantiate the variables I should somehow know its exact type and invoke that specific type's constructor; in the best case this means to have a pretty large if else statement in the constructor, something like:

You'll run into problems before that.

```
   if(var1 instanceof SpecificType1){
      var1 = new SpecificType1(); 
      var2 = new SpecificType2();
   }
```

`var1` is `null` at this point, so `var1 instanceof T` is `false` for all `T`.

---

One limitation of Java generics is that generic type parameters are [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so there's no way that you can reflect on the type parameter from a zero-argument constructor.

The caller has to provide some context to tell you how to initialize `var1` and `var2`, and the typical way to provide that context is via constructor arguments.

---

Your best option is probably to let `var1` and `var2` start off `null` and then delay initialization until such time as you can get the context you need.

Perhaps

```
void init(Class<E> type) {
  if (type.isAssignableFrom(ConcreteType1.class)) {
    var1 = type.cast(new ConcreteType1(...));
    var2 = type.cast(new ConcreteType1(...));
  } else { /* other branches */ }
}
```

This isn't perfect since you still can't distinguish `E extends List<String>` from `E extends List<Number>` but it may be good enough for your case, and the [`.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method will give you a type-safe cast to `E`.

---

Alternatively, Guava, Guice, and related libraries provide things like the [`Supplier<E>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) interface which may come in handy in an `init` method.

Comment: Yes, this was also my intuition. So, the limitations are even more serious!

Comment: I agree to the edit too. I have another constructor which takes 2 E variables as parameters , but the framework wants a no-arg constructor

Comment: The framework would be supposed to call init and it will certainly not do it.

Comment: @Razvan, if you can't split initialization into two steps, can you try creating subclasses with zero-arg ctors which initialize their superclass by passing ctor arguments?  `class StringPair extends Pair<String> { StringPair() { super(String.class); } }` and similarly `class IntegerPair extends Pair<Integer> { IntegerPair() { super(Integer.class); } }`.

Comment: Make the constructor pass in the classes, or the instances

Comment: @MikeSamuel: if I use subclasses do generics make so much sense anymore ?

Comment: @Razvan, if generics let you collect all the common parameter-type-invariant behavior in the base class, leaving only initialization to type-specific subclasses, then I think you gain something by having that generic base class.

Comment: I'd advice against the if's in any case, and try to use reflection to instantiate the variables. Of course you'd need to pass the constructor the name of the classes at least.

Comment: @MisterSmith, overuse of reflection in Java causes problems that would otherwise be caught by the compiler to show up at runtime.  Unless using reflection actually makes code easier to test & maintain, you should avoid it.  `Supplier<T>` and similar interfaces allow clients to specify how creation happens without involving the sledgehammer-to-swat-a-fly that is reflective constructor invocation.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'll have a look at `Supplier`, never heard about it. But you'll agree with me in that the block you commented with `/* other branches */` can grow very large and it is not mainteinable.

Comment: @MisterSmith.  I do not agree.  It may or it may not grow very large.  Assuming it will is premature optimization and reflection makes code less maintainable by delaying until runtime problems that could be caught earlier, obscuring where classes can be used, and putting code that uses it outside the reach of refactoring tools.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate a generic type - What will happen if for example the generic type is `SomeAbstractClass`? What will be instantiated? (this is not the reason, it is just intuition)

However, you can use **[java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)** to instantiate the object - but you will need the specific class object for it.

A more elegant alternative is using the **[abstract factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)**, and pass a factory object to your pair, and use it to construct the needed object.

---

Code sample:

```
public class Pair<S> {
    public final S var1; 
    public final S var2;
    public Pair(Factory<S> builder) {
        var1 = builder.build();
        var2 = builder.build();

    }
}

public interface Factory<S> { 
    public S build();
}

public class IntegerBuilder implements Factory<Integer> {
    private int element = 5;
    public Integer build() {
        return new Integer(element++);
    }
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Just did, is it understandable?

Comment: Excellent. And now for the `Class` method, just for completeness.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I added it as an option - but I strongly advise against it - thus I prefer to leave the factory design pattern code alone - much safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If a framework were to instantiate it, it would do it as a raw type, something equivalent to `new Pair()` with no type parameters.

I guess you have to create simple one-liner classes like:

```
class SpecificType1Pair extends Pair<SpecificType1> {}
```

and pass them to the framework instead. You can get the actual type parameter as `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]`. You class pair would look like this:

```
public abstract class Pair<E extends AClass> {
    private E var1;
    private E var2;

    public Pair() {
        ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        try {
            var1 = clazz.newInstance();
            var2 = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            handle(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` might be in order on the `Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) ...;` line.